# Robust optimization packages in R

Tags: r, optimization, r-package, robustness, robust

I am currently working on Mixed integer linear programming problem and I was wondering if there is any software packages available about Robust Optimization in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: You can consider using the R package DEoptim.